# What is the correct syntax to run the function "getBgColors" as an addListener callback?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am following this tutorial in which the content script **inject.js** queries and counts the number of CSS selectors on a page and returns the data to the background script **event.js**: [Colorpeek, Part 2: Building Your First Chrome Extension | CSS-Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/colorpeek-part-2-building-first-chrome-extension/)

The tutorial example works for `chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(getBgColors)`.

**It does not work** for `chrome.webNavigation.onDOMContentLoaded.addListener(getBgColors)`

**What is the appropriate syntax to call getBgColors from the addListener?**

I have added the following permissions to manifest.json:

```
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["event.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "permissions": [
    "webNavigation",
    "tabs",
    "<all_urls>"
  ]
```

I have confirmed that webNavigation is working by testing the following in event.js:

```
chrome.webNavigation.onDOMContentLoaded.addListener(function(e) {
    alert("SUCCESS!");
}, {url: [{hostSuffix: 'testdomain.com'}]});
```

How can I create same alert using webNavigation that is currently created successfully by `chrome.webNavigation.onDOMContentLoaded.addListener(getBgColors)`?

I'm hoping somebody who understands javascript can help me with the syntax for calling the function "getBgColors" from the webNavigation event listener. I haven't been able to run this function from webNavigation.

How do I make this work?

```
chrome.webNavigation.onDOMContentLoaded.addListener(function(tab) {
    getBgColors(tab); // This should be invoked when I visit the hostSuffix domain.
}, {url: [{hostSuffix: 'testdomain.com'}]});
```

**See code below.**

---

Here is the background script **event.js**:

```
// Execute the inject.js in a tab and call a method,
// passing the result to a callback function.
function injectedMethod (tab, method, callback) {
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, { file: 'inject.js' }, function(){
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, { method: method }, callback);
  });
}

function getBgColors (tab) {
  // When we get a result back from the getBgColors
  // method, alert the data
  injectedMethod(tab, 'getBgColors', function (response) {
    alert('Elements in tab: ' + response.data);
    return true;
  });
}

// Currently alerts with number of elements
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(getBgColors);
// Currently does nothing
chrome.webNavigation.onDOMContentLoaded.addListener(getBgColors);
```

Here is the content script **inject.js**:

```
// This helps avoid conflicts in case we inject 
// this script on the same page multiple times
// without reloading.
var injected = injected || (function(){

  // An object that will contain the "methods"
  // we can use from our event script.
  var methods = {};

  // This method will eventually return
  // background colors from the current page.
  methods.getBgColors = function(){
    var nodes = document.querySelectorAll('*');
    return nodes.length;
  };

  // This tells the script to listen for
  // messages from our extension.
  chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
    var data = {};
    // If the method the extension has requested
    // exists, call it and assign its response
    // to data.
    if (methods.hasOwnProperty(request.method))
      data = methods[request.method]();
    // Send the response back to our extension.
    sendResponse({ data: data });
    return true;
  });

  return true;
})();
```

Comment: RTFM: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation#property-onDOMContentLoaded-callback

Comment: I've edited the question. Can you give an example of the syntax needed to call GetBgColors from the webNavigation listener?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot directly use your "getBgColors" callback in both event listeners, because the parameters are incompatible, as you can clearly see after reading the documentation:

[`chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction#event-onClicked):

> The callback parameter should be a function that looks like this:
>
> `function( tabs.Tab tab) {...};`

[`chrome.webNavigation.onDOMContentLoaded.addListener`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation#property-onDOMContentLoaded-callback)

> The callback parameter should be a function that looks like this:
>
> ```
> function(object details) {...};  
>    object   details
>    integer  tabId   The ID of the tab in which the navigation occurs.
>    ...
> ```

Since your `getBgColors` function only needs `tab.id`, take the tab ID out from the parameters to either event, and call the `getBgColors` method with this tab ID only:

```js
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    getBgColors(tab.id);
});
chrome.webNavigation.onDOMContentLoaded.addListener(function(details) {
    getBgColors(details.tabId);
});

function injectedMethod(tabId, method, callback) {
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, { file: 'inject.js' }, function(){
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabId, { method: method }, callback);
  });
}
```